# Aligning image from php using table

Tags: php, html, css

Im trying to align the image that I fetched from my database with a text that is also fetched from database. The text seems ok but the image just stick to the left

```
<div align="center">
    <p>
    <?php
        $vid =$_REQUEST[@id];
        include 'conn.php';
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_car where Id = '$vid'");

        $vid = 'Id';
        $vnamaproduk = 'NamaProduk';
        $vharga = 'Harga';
        $vpenerangan = 'Penerangan';
        $vgambar = 'Gambar';
    ?>
    <table width="1000" border="0" align="center">
    <?php
        while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="gambar/car/<?php echo $row[$vgambar];?>"width="500" height="400"/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
                echo "<br>Product Id : ".$row[$vid];
                echo "<br>Product Name : ".$row[$vnamaproduk];
                $harganew =sprintf('%0.2f',$row[$vharga]);
                echo "<br>Price : RM".$harganew;
                echo "<br> <br>".$row[$vpenerangan];
                echo "<br>";
            }
            ?>
                ADD TO CART
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the image displayed as a block?

```
img {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the image, you could try this

```
img {
    margin: auto 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a sample/fiddle of what you want to achieve